# call in a method from another class when jbutton is clicked

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I intend to write a public method in one class and make the method work when a button is clicked in another JFrame. the class with the method is below:

```
package Pack.billing;

import Pack.First_Term_Arrears;
import Pack.myKIDS;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
public class Arrears {

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

 public Arrears(){
 conn = myKIDS.connectKids();
 }  

  public void display_all_Arrears(){
    First_Term_Arrears ta = new First_Term_Arrears();
    try{    
    String sql ="select ID,NAME,SURNAME,CLASS,OLD_ARREARS,FEES,PAID,NEW_ARREARS,DATE,CONTACT from All_Arrears";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    ta.ArrearsTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
     }
```

and this is the method I want to use:

```
  public void display_all_Arrears(){
    First_Term_Arrears ta = new First_Term_Arrears();
    try{    
    String sql ="select ID,NAME,SURNAME,CLASS,OLD_ARREARS,FEES,PAID,NEW_ARREARS,DATE,CONTACT from All_Arrears";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    ta.ArrearsTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
     }
```

the button on the other jframe which I want it to perform this action is as follows:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Arrears ar = new Arrears(); ar.first_term_arrears();        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

but nothing works. please what am I doing wrong. thank you

Comment: ohk...can please write a sample code like that for me please @Prabin_Paudel

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the correct method? You say you want to call *display_all_Arrears()* on the *Arrears* instance you create in the button event handler, but instead it calls *first_term_arrears()* which is not an existing method on that class. Try

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Arrears ar = new Arrears(); 
    ar.display_all_Arrears();        
}
```

Comment: This may be the first place it breaks but maybe not the only one.

Comment: first_term_arrears is the name of the jframe which the jtable that has to display the records exists.

Comment: Then please update your question because this is not obvious. You cannot use the name of a JFrame as a method on an instance of Arrears